# SQLite FTS: what is the fast way to get result count with match and limit?

Tags: sqlite, count, full-text-search, match

In SQLite:
Select * from table1 where table1 match 'any word here' limit 10 offset 0;

I need to get total results count, say it will be 10,000

So should I execute another request like:
Select count(*) from table1 where table1 match 'any word here';

Is there more fast solution?

I searched and did not found.

Comment: Your solution is very fast. What is the fastest way to get result counts with grouping by a field in FTS search. For example by BookID. The Group By command is very slow on big database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite calculates result records on the fly.
So when you use the `LIMIT` clause, any records after the tenth will never be seen.

If you need the total count, you must use `COUNT`.

Comment: thanks, so if I use SELECT COUNT after search query it will be more fast than if I used it before, or the same thing?

Comment: And why there is no artifice to calculate results count directly from FTS INDEX or get something like  "about ~ 10,000 result" as Google say?

Comment: Repeated queries on the same data will be faster if the data fits into the cache. While SQLite's FTS was originally written by a Google employee, it does not have all features of the actual Google engine.